# Break line after count of 4

Tags: php, html, css, checkbox

I want to display my check boxes in such a way that after count of 4 rest display in next line upto 4 and then again breaks in next line. Following i the code which i tried but no success -

```
<?php 
  $i=1;
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if( $i<5 ) {
?>
      <input type="checkbox" id="<?=$row['CategoryName']?>" name="<?=$row['CategoryName']?>" /><?=$row['CategoryName']?>
<?
      $i++;
    }
?>
  <br />
<?php
  $i=1;
  }
?>
```

Comment: can you ident your code for better readability?

Comment: @barts Done. Probably the reason for the mistake was the (bad) idention.

Comment: surprised how few proposed answers use %.  Seems like such an obvious modulo problem.  why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
<?php 
    $i=1;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
       if( $i<5 )
        {                           
?>
<input type="checkbox" id="<?=$row['CategoryName']?>" name="<?=$row['CategoryName']?>" /><?=$row['CategoryName']?>
<?php
        $i++;
        }
       else {
    ?>
    <br />
    <?php
        $i=1;
       }
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Thx for the code, works perfectly for me(maybe some people posted better sol but it clicked for me so ticked ur sol as accepted ) :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest this:

```
<?php 
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="<?=$row['CategoryName']?>" name="<?=$row['CategoryName']?>" /><?=$row['CategoryName']?>
    <?php
    $i++
    if ( $i % 4 == 0 ) echo '<br />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: This will put a single item on the first row

Comment: @alexn why would it put a single item on first line?  first iteration $i==1 before if check.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `.eq()` - http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Check the code here - http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2011/01/ul-count-li-elements-display-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `if (fmod($i, 4) == 0)` instead of `if ($i < 5)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $i++;
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="'.$row['CategoryName'].'" name="'.$row['CategoryName'].'" />'.$row['CategoryName'];
    if($i % 4 == 0) {
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: This will put a single item on the first row.

Comment: @alexn Edited and repaired the code... Thank You for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator to achieve this. Example:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    echo $i . "&nbsp;";
    if ($i % 4 == 3)
        echo "<br />";
}
```

Yields

```
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 
12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please try code given below

```
<?php 
   $i=1;
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   if( $i<5 ) {
 ?>
     <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $row['CategoryName']; ?>"  
      name="?=$row['CategoryName']?>" /> 
<?php 
    echo $row['CategoryName']; 
    $i++;
  }else{
?>
 <br />
 <?php
 $i=1;
 }
}
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 1;
for($x = 0; $x < 20; $x++) {
echo "your element here";
if($i%4==0){
echo "</br>";
}
$i++;
}
```

Regards : [TechNew.In](http://www.technew.in/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of answers with ready solutions, so instead writing more code I will propose you a systematical approach:
Start with writing algorithm, then write code.

1. I want to iterate through my set of data:

   ```
   // while row
       // echo input
   // end while
   ```
2. I want a linebreak after a predefined number of inputs:

   ```
   // break_after = 4
   // initiate counter (counter = 0)
   // while row
       // increment counter
       // echo input
       // if counter == break_after
           // echo linebreak
           // reset counter
   // end while
   ```
3. Replace comments with code:

   ```
   die('Piece of cake...');
   ```

   (I said I will not write code. You already know how to do it.)